# i'm trying to do an infinite scroll and i'm getting "React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, performance, infinite-scroll

I have a problem, I'm trying to do an infinite scroll but I'm getting the following error "Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop. at .../ReceivedBoxes.jsx:53:33 in getReceivedBoxes"

I would like to know, where is the error in my code, I believe that I am changing the state even if indirectly.

I'm new to React Native, so I'm having some difficulty.

```
import { useCallback, useContext, useEffect, useMemo, useState } from "react";
import { FlatList, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity, View } from "react-native";
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native-safe-area-context";
import { Box, Center, HStack, Icon, Text, VStack } from "native-base";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";

import { authContext } from "../contexts/auth.context";

import { Api } from "../utils/api.util";

import { HeaderComponent } from "../components/Header";
import { ButtonComponent } from "../components/Button";
import { ImageComponent } from "../components/Image";
import { MemoizedTouchableReceivedBox } from "../components/TouchableReceivedBox";
import { MemoizedTouchableBoxReceivedInProcessing } from "../components/TouchableReceivedBoxInProcessing";

export function ReceivedBoxes() {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const { token } = useContext(authContext);

  const [receivedBoxes, setReceivedBoxes] = useState([]);
  const [rbInProcessing, setRBInProcessing] = useState([]);

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const [lastPage, setLastPage] = useState(undefined);

  
  useEffect(() => {
    getReceivedBoxesInProcessing();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    getReceivedsBoxes();
  }, []);

  async function getReceivedsBoxes() {
    if (loading || currentPage > lastPage) return;
  
    setLoading(true);
  
    try {
      const response = await Api({
        route: `receiving?page=${currentPage}&image_size=small`,
        method: "GET",
      }, token);
  
      const { success, receiving, pagination } = await response.json();
  
      success ? setReceivedBoxes(prev => [...prev, ...receiving]) : null;
      setLastPage(pagination.last_page);
      setCurrentPage(pagination.current_page + 1);
    } catch (e) {
      console.warn(e);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }

  async function getReceivedBoxesInProcessing() {
    try {
      const response = await Api({
        route: `receiving/processing?page=1&image_size=small`,
        method: "GET",
      }, token);

      const { success, receiving } = await response.json();

      if(success) {
        setRBInProcessing(receiving);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.warn(e);
    }
  }

  const renderItemReceivedBox = useCallback(({ item }) => (
    <MemoizedTouchableReceivedBox
      key={item.key}
      id={item.id} 
      title={item.origin_tracking_number}
      qty={item.qty}
      weight_pound={item.weight_lbs}
      images={item.images}
      date={String(item.received_date)}
    />
  ), []);

  const memoizedValue = useMemo(() => renderItemReceivedBox, []);

  function EmptyListMessage() { 
    return (
      <View style={{ alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
        <Text textAlign="center">Não há caixas recebidas a serem exibidas</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ backgroundColor: "#e6e6e6", height: "100%" }}>
      <HeaderComponent hasArrowBackButton={true} title="Caixas Recebidas" />

      <View style={{ marginHorizontal: 10, marginTop: 5 }}>
        <Center>
          <Box width="80%">
            <ButtonComponent 
              buttonProps={{
                text: "Localize sua encomenda",
                isBold: true,
                action: () => { navigation.navigate("LocateUrOrder") }
              }}
            />
          </Box>
        </Center>

        <Box marginBottom={6}>
          <Box marginTop={6} marginBottom={3} width="100%" flexDirection="row" justifyContent="space-between">
            <Box>
              <Text fontSize={18} color="#15294B">Caixas em processamento</Text>
            </Box>

            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {}}>
              <Box backgroundColor="#FFF" paddingX={5} paddingY={1} borderRadius={15}>
                <Text fontSize={16} color="#894AFF">Ver tudo</Text>
              </Box>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </Box>

          <ScrollView horizontal>
            {
              rbInProcessing.map(receivedBox => (
                <MemoizedTouchableBoxReceivedInProcessing
                  key={receivedBox.key}
                  id={receivedBox.id} 
                  title={receivedBox.origin_tracking_number}
                  images={receivedBox.images}
                  date={receivedBox.received_date}
                />
              ))
            }
          </ScrollView>
        </Box>

        <Box marginBottom={6}>
          <View style={{ height: "90%" }}>
            <FlatList
              data={receivedBoxes}
              renderItem={memoizedValue}
              keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
              onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
              onEndReached={getReceivedsBoxes}
              ListEmptyComponent={EmptyListMessage}
              contentContainerStyle={{ paddingBottom: 100 }}
            />
          </View>
        </Box>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

I would like infinite scroll to work.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, the error could potentially be coming from the `getReceivedsBoxes()` function, which is called repeatedly within the component due to the infinite scroll implementation.

The issue might be caused by the fact that you are updating the state in `getReceivedsBoxes()` using the `setReceivedBoxes()` function within the `success` conditional, even if the `success` value is false. This means that if the response from the API call is not successful, the `setReceivedBoxes()` function would not be called, and the state would not be updated. However, you still update the `lastPage` and `currentPage` states regardless of whether the API call was successful or not.

This could potentially lead to an infinite loop of state updates, causing the "Too many re-renders" error. To fix this, you could update your `getReceivedsBoxes()` function to only update the state and pagination values if the API call is successful, like so:

```
async function getReceivedsBoxes() {
  if (loading || currentPage > lastPage) return;

  setLoading(true);

  try {
    const response = await Api({
      route: `receiving?page=${currentPage}&image_size=small`,
      method: "GET",
    }, token);

    const { success, receiving, pagination } = await response.json();

    if (success) {
      setReceivedBoxes(prev => [...prev, ...receiving]);
      setLastPage(pagination.last_page);
      setCurrentPage(pagination.current_page + 1);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.warn(e);
  } finally {
    setLoading(false);
  }
}
```

This way, the state is only updated when the API call is successful, and the `lastPage` and `currentPage` states are only updated when new data is received.

Also, you may want to remove the `useMemo()` hook and `memoizedValue` variable, as it doesn't seem necessary in your current implementation.